# Calculate length between bar_index in pinescript

Tags: pine-script

Want to calculate the highest `close` between `test_X1` bar and `bar_index` and then plot this line **only** if that highest `close` is not greater than **10% increase** in `test_y`

When I try to use `highest()`, it expects me to use integer value for `length`, `bar_index-test_x1` is still a series.

```
//@version=4
study(title="Test", shorttitle="Test", format=format.volume, overlay=true)

var line    hline                   = line.new(na, na, na, na, extend=extend.right, color=color.white)
var test_y = -1.0
var test_x1 = -1.0

if close > close[2]
    line.set_xy1(hline, bar_index - 20, close)
    line.set_xy2(hline, bar_index,      close)
    test_y := close
    test_x1 := bar_index
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
//@version=4
study(title="Test", shorttitle="Test", format=format.volume, overlay=true)

var bars_back = input(20)

var line    hline = line.new(na, na, na, na, extend=extend.right, color=color.white)

hc = highest(close, bars_back)

if barstate.islast and (close <= hc * 1.1)
    line.set_xy1(hline, bar_index - bars_back,  hc)
    line.set_xy2(hline, bar_index,              hc)
else
    line.set_xy1(hline, na, na)
    line.set_xy2(hline, na, na)
```